# Xcode 9.0 simulators "disappeared"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I recently installed Xcode 9.0 GM on my machine. I fired it up to play around and the only simulators I see in the scheme are iPhone 8, iPHone 8 Plus, and iPhone X. I clicked "Download Additional Simulators" thinking the solution would lie there.

[image]

I'm greeted with this screen, which is everything I previously had installed.

[image]

I dug around on the Apple Developer forum and found [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63420) discussing a similar problem with a prior version of iOS. At the suggestion of one of the posters, I powered down my machine and booted it cold. I opened up Xcode 9.0 again and I have the same issue.

Any suggestions what I can get additional hardware to appear in my Xcode scheme? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In Xcode 10.3, I also lost all simulators but got them back by running

`sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Looks like the Xcode 10.3 update derped all simulators, just great. In another thread someone suggested rebooting his Mac fixed the problem.

Comment: Noticed this after the 10.3 update as well when I was trying to convert a Ray Wenderlich project to Swift 5.0.  Noticed all simulators were gone, this cleared up both issues.

Comment: Also had this happen after the Xcode 10.3 update. Thanks

Comment: How did you find out that you had to run exactly this command in order to reset the simulators? Incredible!

Comment: Somebody suggested it in an apple developer forum that I came across when googling the issue

Comment: Thank you! but the question remains, how in the name of God one would guess this coreservice is down or by the same token... that it exists. I hope you don't mind me asking but how did you come to know this?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else gets here and are in my situation, I just upgraded to Xcode 9.2 and the simulators were all missing, but quitting and relaunching Xcode restored them.

Answer (score 4):

For me quitting and relaunching Xcode also didn't help. So I did the following 3 steps.

Three steps

Step 1:

Product -> Destination -> Download Simulators... Download the simulator(s) you need

Step 2:

Sometimes when you download the new simulator types, they don't automatically show in the list of possible simulators.

Product -> Destination -> Add Additional Simulators... Click the + button in the lower left hand corner, then Add Simulator Give it a name, device type, and the iOS version you just downloaded.

Step 3:

Set proper deployment target. If you have downloaded simulators of lower versions, set the deployment target to the same.

Now it should show up in your list of simulator devices!

Comment: For the record, "Add Additional Simulators" worked for me. Restarting Xcode or restarting the computer didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Delete every single one of the simulators listed in the Devices and Simulators window, one by one, and then start over make new simulators. That always works for me. It's a good idea after *any* upgrade, in fact.

Comment: You will find that the iPhone 8 and X will have lost their names and will be called 2017-A and so on. But there's nothing you can do about that. It's a beta, even though it's called a GM.

Comment: Awesome! I had one that was "stubborn", so I went to the directory via Finder and deleted it. If anyone else encounters the same issue, they're found in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UDID]`. Details here--> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65272

Comment: Before deleting and adding them all manually, try the command I suggested below, might save a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

My question was originally answered, but I found a more efficient way to do it with [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools). Within `fastlane`, there's a tool called [snapshot](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/snapshot/). The usage is as follows from terminal:

`fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`

> Warning: This will delete all your simulators and replace by new ones! This is useful, if you run into weird problems when running snapshot.

Comment: Simple and easy.  Does require fastlane; however, I had it installed and it worked like a champ. Install it via homebrew and you can get it up and running.